Configuring Apexcharter Treemap labels and colors
I am currently experimentating with treemap plots with apexcharter and I am trying to replicate some functionnalities that I used in my previous plots.
1 - I would like to display the y value (or the percentage of that y value like in a pie plot) below the x label. I only found that graph which seems to do that, but I can't seem to be able to reproduce it in R. You can find my attempt to replicate it in the ax_dataLabels() function.
2 - The colors displayed in the distributed treemap are not the ones I defined in ax_colors(), or rather they seem to be gradients between them. I wonder what causes this and how I can force the chart to use exactly the ones defined.
There doesn't seem to be a lot documentation of apexcharter treemaps in R and it looks like they need to be configured a bit differentrly from the pie and bar charts.
Here is the code used :
library(tidyverse)
library(apexcharter)

dummy_data <- tibble(
  Material = c("Lead", "Tin", "Iron", "Copper", "Mercury", "Silver", "Gold"),
  Quantities = c(18, 15, 12, 10, 11, 40, 100)
)

apex(dummy_data, type = "treemap", mapping = aes(x = Material, y = Quantities)) %>%
  ax_colors(c('#001219', '#005F73', '#0A9396', '#E9D8A6', '#EE9B00', '#CA6702', '#BB3E03')) %>%
  ax_dataLabels(
    enabled = TRUE, 
    style = list(
      fontSize = "18px", 
      formatter = JS("function(text, op) {
                        return [text, op.value]
                     }")
    )) %>%
  ax_plotOptions(treemap = list(distributed = TRUE)) %>%
  ax_chart(toolbar = FALSE)

